# Pagination work but error

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

my script code search with pagination, work! but when I click on next page the server writes this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: byidaifa in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\search.php on
>   line 129
>
> Notice: Undefined index: byidaifa in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\search.php on
>   line 147
>
> Notice: Undefined index: byidaifa in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\search.php on
>   line 187

The "byidaifa" is INT numeric on IDAIFA in mysql.
it seems as if it must remain empty!

where is the error?

many thanks!

```
<?php
        include('conn.php');    
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['byidaifa']=$_REQUEST['byidaifa'];
        $_SESSION['bynome']=$_REQUEST ['bynome'];
        $_SESSION['bycognome']=$_REQUEST ['bycognome'];
        $_SESSION['bytipologia']=$_REQUEST ['bytipologia'];
        $_SESSION['bymarca']=$_REQUEST ['bymarca'];
        $_SESSION['bymodello']=$_REQUEST ['bymodello'];
        $_SESSION['bystato']=$_REQUEST ['bystato'];
        $_SESSION['bysoftware']=$_REQUEST ['bysoftware'];

        $limit = 50; 

        $count = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM asset WHERE ID ";

        if($_REQUEST['byidaifa'])
            $count = $count . " AND IDAIFA LIKE '".$_SESSION['byidaifa']."' ";

        if($_REQUEST ['bynome'])
            $count = $count . " AND Nome LIKE '".$_SESSION['bynome']."' ";  

        if($_REQUEST ['bycognome'])
            $count = $count . " AND Cognome LIKE '".$_SESSION['bycognome']."' ";    

        if($_REQUEST ['bytipologia'])
            $count = $count . " AND Tipologia LIKE '".$_SESSION['bytipologia']."' ";    

        if($_REQUEST ['bymarca'])
            $count = $count . " AND Marca LIKE '".$_SESSION['bymarca']."' ";    

        if($_REQUEST ['bymodello'])
            $count = $count . " AND Modello LIKE '".$_SESSION['bymodello']."' ";

        if($_REQUEST ['bystato'])
            $count = $count . " AND Stato LIKE '".$_SESSION['bystato']."' ";

        if($_REQUEST ['bysoftware'])
            $count = $count . " AND Software LIKE '".$_SESSION['bysoftware']."' ";              

            $resultcount = mysql_query($count);

            $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($count));
            $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

            $stages = 3;

        $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']) : 0;
        if($page){
            $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
        }else{
            $start = 0; 
            }   

            $querysearch = "SELECT * FROM asset WHERE ID ";

        if($_REQUEST['byidaifa'])
            $querysearch = $querysearch . " AND IDAIFA LIKE '".$_SESSION['byidaifa']."' ";

        if($_REQUEST ['bynome'])
            $querysearch = $querysearch . " AND Nome LIKE '".$_SESSION['bynome']."' ";  

        if($_REQUEST ['bycognome'])
            $querysearch = $querysearch . " AND Cognome LIKE '".$_SESSION['bycognome']."' ";    

        if($_REQUEST ['bytipologia'])
            $querysearch = $querysearch . " AND Tipologia LIKE '".$_SESSION['bytipologia']."' ";    

        if($_REQUEST ['bymarca'])
            $querysearch = $querysearch . " AND Marca LIKE '".$_SESSION['bymarca']."' ";    

        if($_REQUEST ['bymodello'])
            $querysearch = $querysearch . " AND Modello LIKE '".$_SESSION['bymodello']."' ";

        if($_REQUEST ['bystato'])
            $querysearch = $querysearch . " AND Stato LIKE '".$_SESSION['bystato']."' ";

        if($_REQUEST ['bysoftware']){
            $querysearch = $querysearch . " AND Software LIKE '".$_SESSION['bysoftware']."' ";  
            }
            $querysearch = $querysearch . " LIMIT $start, $limit ";

            $resultsearch = mysql_query($querysearch);

            if(isset($_REQUEST))
                                 {
                                   unset($_REQUEST['page']);
                                   $querysearch = http_build_query($_REQUEST);
                                 }

            // Initial page num setup
        if ($page == 0){$page = 1;}
        $prev = $page - 1;  
        $next = $page + 1;                          
        $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
        $LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;                    

        $paginate = '';
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
            // Previous
            if ($page > 1){
                $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=$prev'>Prev</a> ";
            }else{
                $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";   }

            // Pages    
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2))
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                   
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2))
            {
                if($page < 1 + ($stages * 2))       
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page){
                            $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                        }else{
                            $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                   
                    }
                    $paginate.= "...";
                    $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                    $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";      
                }

                elseif($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2))
                {
                    $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=1'>1</a>";
                    $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=2'>2</a>";
                    $paginate.= "...";
                    for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page){
                            $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                        }else{
                            $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                   
                    }
                    $paginate.= "...";
                    $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                    $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";      
                }
                else
                {
                    $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=1'>1</a>";
                    $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=2'>2</a>";
                    $paginate.= "...";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page){
                            $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                        }else{
                            $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                   
                    }
                }
            }

                    // Next
            if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
                $paginate.= "<a href='search.php?search=$querysearch&submit=Go&page=$next'>next</a>";
            }else{
                $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
                }

            $paginate.= "</div>";       


    }
     echo $total_pages.' Results';
     // pagination


     echo "<table border='1' style='margin:0 auto;'>";

    echo "<tr>",
    "<td colspan='3'> Azioni </td> <td> Nome </td> <td> Cognome </td> <td> IDAIFA </td> <td> Utilizzo</td> <td> Tipologia</td> <td>Marca</td> <td>Modello</td> <td>Stato</td>",
    "</tr> \n";

            if ($resultsearch)
            while($dati = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsearch))
            {

            echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> <a href='detailasset.php?ID=$dati[ID]'><img src='../images/eye.png'></a> </td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='modasset.php?ID=$dati[ID]'><img src='../images/edit.png'></a> </a> </td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='deleteasset.php?ID=$dati[ID]?confirm=true' class='confirm'> <img src='../images/delete.png'></a></td>";

    print "<td> $dati[Nome] </td>";
    print "<td> $dati[Cognome] </td>";
    print "<td> $dati[IDAIFA] </td>";
    print "<td> $dati[Utilizzo] </td>";
    print "<td> $dati[Tipologia] </td>";
    print "<td> $dati[Marca] </td>";
    print "<td> $dati[Modello] </td>";
    print "<td> $dati[Stato] </td>";
    print "<td> $dati[Software] </td>";


    echo "</tr> \n";

            }

        echo "</table></div>\n";
         echo $paginate;
        ?>
```

Comment: use `$count .= "..." ` instead of `$count = $count . "..."`

Comment: FYI: Notice not the same as Error, you *can* suppress notices and all your code will still work

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz They are the same thing. Though it would clean up his code.

OP, could you post what lines are lines 129, 147, and 187?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't sure whether or not a variable will be set or not, put a check in for if it is set before calling it e.g.:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['byidaifa']){
$_SESSION['byidaifa']=$_REQUEST['byidaifa'];
}
else{
$_SESSION['byidaifa'] = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like byidaifa doesn't exist in your request. Instead of using `if($_REQUEST ['byidaifa'])`, use `if(!empty($_REQUEST ['byidaifa']))` to make sure that it exists in the request and holds a value that isn't NULL or FALSE. Do the same with the other `if($_REQUEST)`s to make sure those errors don't pop up again

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if `$_REQUEST` params are defined / not null before trying to access them. You can do this with the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or empty function.

```
 $_SESSION['byidaifa']= (isset($_REQUEST['byidaifa']) ) ? $_REQUEST['byidaifa'] : NULL;
```

Later
`if(is_null($_SESSION['byidaifa']) === false )` [...]

You really should sanitize inputs and use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to access database as mysql function are deprecated. For now your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).